# Trying and failing to use a module inside of another module

Tags: angular, typescript

I am reletively new to the Angular world so there might be something going over my head but here is my issue.

My web page displays nothing as soon as I import my "tabsModule" and I am unsure why.

As far as I can tell there isn't anything wrong with my module.

```
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { secFuncListComponent } from "../moduleSecFunc/secFunc-list.component";
import { moduleSecFuncComponent } from "../moduleSecFunc/moduleSecFunc.component";
import { favoritesComponent } from "../favorites/favorites.component";
import { recentComponent } from "../recent/recent.component";
import { recentContainerComponent } from "../recentContainer/recentContainer.component";
import { mostUsedComponent } from "../mostUsed/mostUsed.component";
import { tabsComponent } from "./tabs.component";

import { secFunc, secFuncService, Favorites, UserCompanies } from '../moduleSecFunc/secFunc.server';

@NgModule({
    imports:[
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {path: 'tabs', component:tabsComponent}
        ])
    ],
    declarations:[
        secFuncListComponent,
        moduleSecFuncComponent,
        favoritesComponent,
        recentComponent,
        recentContainerComponent,
        mostUsedComponent,
        tabsComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [tabsComponent]
})
export class tabsModule{ }
```

in the app module I

```
import { tabsModule } from "./tabs/tabs.module";
```

and

```
imports: [
    tabsModule
  ],
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please include any console error you may be generating

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: add `export` field to your module annotation

Answer (score 0):

When declaring modules in angular, a few attributes can be set in the @ngModule annotation:

- imports : the modules your new module depends on
- declarations : the components and directives declared in this module (and thus usable internaly)
- providers : the services declared in this module (usable internaly and externaly)
- exports : the components and directives that are accessible externaly.

In your example, your components are set in 'declarations', so they are visible internaly. To allow someone to use them from outside this module (after importing it), you must add the components to 'exports' AS WELL. You will then be able to use them outside of your module.